# Does a "lose your turn" card cancel doubles?

Tags: monopoly

In Monopoly, if I roll doubles and land on Chance/Community Chest and receive a "lose your next turn" card, does that cancel my doubles and I get to take my next turn? Do I take my doubles and lose my next turn? Do I lose both?

Comment: I don't recall a Monopoly card that causes you to lose your turn.  Which version are you playing?

Comment: @BJMyers Many of the newer versions have such a card

Comment: Yes but which one we need accurate information

Comment: Jerusalem edition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [a version of the rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/monins.pdf) hopefully not too different from yours, doubles are described like this:

> If you throw doubles, you move your token as usual... **Retaining the dice, throw again**...

It does **not** say "take another turn", so the extra move from doubles is still part of the same turn even though the action you're taking looks a lot like a new turn. Thus if you are told to "lose your **next** turn" after rolling doubles, you should still finish your current turn normally by rolling again.

If however your rules (or insistent other players) say the reroll *is* a new turn, then since it's your next turn you would lose it, but you would *not* lose the following turn.

Comment: Or is "throw again" the same as "take another turn"? I'll have to check my rules to see if you can make the same inference.

Comment: Yeah, I could see it going the other way depending on minor text differences; the one answer that would really not make sense is losing the doubles _and_ the following turn. Either the reroll _is_ your next turn or it isn't; in neither case should you lose both. Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Yep, mine says [take another turn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1BHx.jpg).

Comment: @DonielF The wording in your rules is sort of non-sensical. If rolling doubles gives you "another turn," you could never "roll a double 3 times in the same turn" and "Go To Jail."